# How can I disable the IMAPI.exe service in Windows Vista and Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, imap, services, imgburn

I want to disable the IMAPI CD Burner service because I keep getting `Power Calibration Error` messages.

In Windows XP, it's through `services.msc`, but I can't seem to find it anywhere in Windows 7 or Windows Vista.

Does anyone know how to disable or kill that service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That service doesn't exist in Windows 7 or Vista. The only thing you can do is disable burning from the shell through Group Policy. As for your error there are a few things you can try:

1. See if there are any firmware upgrades for your burner
2. Try to clean the burner.
3. One person on the following [post](http://www.megaleecher.net/Fix_Power_Calibration_Error) recommended downloading the following [file](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/?DiagID=100001&EulaAccept=Yes), which he says fixed some problems that led to the error going away.